# kotlin version that is used for building with gradle (1.1.2-5) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.1.2-4)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Has anyone solved this issue?

> kotlin version that is used for building with gradle (1.1.2-5) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.1.2-4)

I am using AS 3.0 Canary 4

Comment: Try either upgrading plug-in (Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates -> Check for updates now) or downgrading `ext.kotlin_version` in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 311):

I followed [Miha_x64](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3050249/miha-x64)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644524/kotlin-version-that-is-used-for-building-with-gradle-1-1-2-5-differs-from-the#comment76280234_44644524) and upgraded the plugin which solved my problem:

> `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates` -> `Check for updates now`

My version of Android Studio is:

```
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
```

Comment: Yes, perfect
Thank you, should be marked as right answer

Comment: This is not working for me! When I follow these steps, AS tells me "You have the latest version of the plugin installed", but the installed version is 1.5.31, yet according to the Kotlin website, the latest version is 1.6.21..... Help!

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård unfortunately I don't have an answer for you, but if you ever do figure it out, please remember to post what you did to fix the issue.
Maybe you can try reinstalling your AS?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to get back to this... I managed to solve it by putting the higher version of Kotlin in my `app/build.gradle` file, and then it worked! :) It was weird... But AS must have downloaded it while building, even thought it couldn't find it from the Tools menu!... I might post an answer about it later.

Answer (score 101):

In my case, I converted Java to Kotlin and I have already Kotlin installed with lower version. So I updated it.

`Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates` then `Check for updates now` then choose `Stable`

[image: Kotlin]
.

But it didn't update my version in the `build.gradle` file automatically. Because it detected a newer version and differs from the old one.

So I manually updated my version to the latest from

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'` to  `ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really surprising that they have such a basic flaw in their setup that you can configure the classpath to the latest via a shell script in one place but not the other.

Comment: Thank you, the point is after you update the plugin you must change the previous version into current version at  `build.gradle`

Comment: This worked for me, sugg: Anyone doing this might need to add "mavenCentral()" before jcentre() in 2 places.

Comment: This is not working for me! When I follow these steps, AS tells me "You have the latest version of the plugin installed", but the installed version is 1.5.31, yet according to the Kotlin website, the latest version is 1.6.21! Even after changing "stable" to "Early Access Preview", AS still doesn't find any newer version.... Help!

Answer (score 5):

There's an [issue in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62697211) that prevents it from loading the updated version of the Kotlin plugin. You can ignore the warning shown by the Kotlin plugin in build.gradle until a newer version of Android Studio 3.0 is released.

Comment: Still present in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6

Comment: in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7 too

Comment: in Android studio 3.1 Canary 3 also.

Comment: also seen in Android Studio 3.3. Canary 3

Comment: and in Android Studio 3.2 stable too

Comment: Also in Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: Even in Arcticfox. RockRock's answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue, I am using Android Studio 3.2.1

Change the Kotlin version of your **project build.gradle file**(not module build.gradle file) to latest(at the moment it is 1.3.11)

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
```

then there will be notification call Kotlin migration, click Run migrations link on the notification.

Answer (score 3):

1): Open your project in Android mode.

2): Go to build.gradle file(Project: android) level,
which is also located below the gradle folder in Project mode
and open it.

3): It will start with something like this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

4): See that in above example that the

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

5): Now go to File menu in the Top-Left of Android Studio and open Settings.

6): Click on Plugins and select Installed on the top of the settings window.

7): Now scroll down to Kotlin, select it and see it's version, for example:-

221-1.8.0-release-for-android-studio-AS5591.52.

8): Here 1.8.0 is your Android Studio Kotlin plugin version, which is different from your `ext.kotlin_version` in `build.gradle`.

9): So, just make your ex.kotlin_version same as Kotlin plugin version and you're good to go!

10): In above example the ex.kotlin_version = is '1.7.10 and Kotlin Plugin
version is '1.8.0'.
If I type '1.8.0' in my ex.kotlin_version, making my plugin version same  as ex.kotlin_version and sync it, the issue gets resolved. Hope this helps!, I,m also  new in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Go to plugins then uninstall kotlin then restart ide then once android studio is back up  drop down tools then select kotline then configure updates, it should be checking for new updates.

Comment: This worked for me. Before uninstalling Kotlin plugin, the bundled version was 1.7.10, which was giving me errors. After reinstalling, it was 1.6.10, which works.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your build gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score -1):

[![In my case I had to downgrade to Gradle 7.2.2

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGus.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGus.png)

[image: And I'm using stable Kotlin version]