# How to configure flutter project in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I installed all the flutter requirements including the flutter and dart plugins for android studio successfully and nothing is missing. I created a new flutter project without selecting Kotlin support, yet after I created the project I got this code with problem related to kotlin

> Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.2.71) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.3.50)

And this is the build.gradle file code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The other problem is in this diretory : android/app/src/build.gradle. 
I get an error related to the line of code :

> throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

When I move the mouse on the function name I see this :

> Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'

This is the gradle.properties content:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Update kotlin in the build.gradle to the following:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

or check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644524/kotlin-version-that-is-used-for-building-with-gradle-1-1-2-5-differs-from-the)

---

Inside the `local.properties` file add the path to the flutter sdk location:

```
flutter.sdk=/path/to/your/flutter/sdk
flutter.buildMode=debug
```

Comment: after I edited local.properties it seems that the line 'flutter.build= debug' is 'not used' like what appeared to me.
I already have this in the local.properties: 
`
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\Fateh\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter sdk\\flutter
 
`
do I need to change something ?

Comment: is the location to the fluttersdk correct? If it is you might need to change `flutter sdk` this folder to this `flutter-sdk` and then change it in your local.properties file

Comment: @TestProject have you tried changing the name without space?